# Creating cookie using node.js

Tags: node.js, cookies, backend

how do I create cookie in node.js in the root route (i.e. localhost:3000/ ) I am able to create cookie in other routes (such as localhost:3000/createcookie) but how to do it when user opens localhost:3000.

I have tried to create it in the root route just by pasting 'res.cookie('user', 'user1');' in the root route funtion. It is working when it is in other routes but not working in the root route.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `res.cookie()` you should (install and) use Express and cookie-parser from NPM

Comment: please read the question properly... I am having trouble in creating the cookie in the root route itself.